# How after Observable.timer finished/reset throw event/console.log

Tags: observable, angular2-observables

Good day.
I've got Observable.timer that works correct after finished and throw event.
But if I reset work of this Observable.timer I've got that event. I want got event only if Timer finished.

Example code:

```
start(): void {
    this.timer = Observable.timer(this.countDuration, 1000)
      .map(i => this.type === 'count-down' ? this.countDuration - i : this.counter + i)
      .take(this.countDuration + 1)
      .do(i => this.counting = i)
      .finally(() => console.log('hello!'))
      .subscribe();
  }

reset(): void {
    this.countDuration = this.duration;
    this.timer.unsubscribe();
    this.start();
  }
```